# keeping sliding drawer open when handle is touched

Tags: android, android-layout

How can you keep a sliding drawer from closing when it is open and I touch the top?   The sliding drawer is on same page as video player which likes to climb to the top. what steps do I need to take.  In the sliding drawer handle I have a button which I want to click, but it closes the moment I touch the button (which is inside a linear layout within the the slider handle).  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can open and clos sliding drawer [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/) post use

```
 slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened() {
                    slideButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.closearrow);
                }
            });

            slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed() {
                    slideButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.openarrow);
                }
            });
```